# Ranking Numbers with #N/A in List

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to rank numbers that also has #N/A in the list. I have seen suggestions on using countif but that method hasn't been so fruitful. One thought is that because the numbers/values in the list are being generated using a formula (in this case an index and iferror formula), Excel is unable to recognize the outputs as number values that can be ranked. I tried to change the formatting to be numbers but that has not worked so far. Here's the formula that's being used to generate the numbers that need to be ranked:

```
={IFERROR(INDEX($BT$12:$BT$272,$BV13,COLUMNS($BW$12:BW13)),#N/A)}
```

And the outputs range anywhere 1950-2015 including a bunch of #N/A. Any ideas on how to rank these numbers?

Comment: would using the NUMBER function nested within the RANK function work?

Comment: I found a long-winded solution. Basically I add 0 to the values and this turns it into a number and then I rank those values. This works but I'm really trying to avoid creating too many helper columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why excel is unable to rank my list is because the outputs are not numbers. Here's a way around it:

```
={IFERROR(INDEX($BT$12:$BT$272,$BV13,COLUMNS($BW$12:BW13))+0,"")}
```

If you add a ZERO, this converts the output into a number. Now you can finally rank the outputs. Simple solution but works. Thanks to everyone that chimed in - thinking out loud definitely helped!

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Change the formula that generates the numbers to be ranked as follows:

   ```
   ={IFERROR(INDEX($BT$12:$BT$272,$BV13,COLUMNS($BW$12:BW13)),"")}
   ```

   Blank (`""`) will not cause the same issues with ranking that `#N/A` does.
2. If it's important that you continue to have `#N/A` in the column, create a helper column that puts the result of the original column, except replaces `#N/A` with blank. Assuming your column with `#N/A` values is `BX`, you could do that by copying the following formula down column `BY`:

   ```
   =IFERROR(BX12,"")
   ```

   Then you would apply your `RANK` formula to look at `BY` instead of `BX`.

Comment: thanks for the response - keeping #N/A is not important so went with suggestion #1 but still getting a value not available (#N/A) error. also another thing I did on the resulting numbers was the ISNUMBER function and what I got back was a false meaning that the outputs are not in a number format. Perhaps if I can force the output to be a number it might work?...

Comment: @JKo_FinanceUse, For that problem, I would suggest using the `VALUE` formula. That will turn a text representation of a number into an actual number that can be ranked.

Answer (score 1):

The newer [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was designed to ignore errors in cells (option **6**) and has both [LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) and [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) sub-functions that can be used for ascending or descending pseudo-[RANK](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANK-function-6A2FC49D-1831-4A03-9D8C-C279CF99F723) functions.

As array formulas² in BU12:BV12,

```
'ranked in ascending order
=IFERROR(MATCH(BT12, AGGREGATE(15, 6, BT$12:BT$272, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(BT$12:BT$272)))), 0), "")
'ranked in descending order
=IFERROR(MATCH(BT12, AGGREGATE(14, 6, BT$12:BT$272, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(BT$12:BT$272)))), 0), "")
```

The [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) wrapper avoids the display of any error produced from attempting to directly RANK a `#N/A`.

[image: rank_aggregate]

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

² <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change you error result to an extreme:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($BT$12:$BT$272,$BV13,COLUMNS($BW$12:BW13)),99999)
```

or it can be zero depend on direction.  Then you can apply a custom format of:

```
[<>99999]0;"#N/A"
```

This will put `#N/A` for the errors but keep a number in the background.

Then your rank formula:

```
=IF(A1=99999,"",RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$100))
```

Obviously change the references to match yours.